# Calculate value using row above in data.frame and another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I want to do something in R that seems like it should be simple but I seem to be having a brain fade.

For each row in a data.frame I want to get the value of `Vol` in row above, add value of `In` for that row and minus a value dependent on this value.

Here is my attempt but lag is just looking one row back for the values at the start, not continuing to look back once the next value has been calculated

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(In = c(1,4,0,0,1,2,3,0,0), Vol = c(1,rep(NA,8)))

df %>% mutate(Vol = (lag(Vol) + In) -  (lag(Vol) + In)*0.01)
```

desired output =

```
  In     Vol
1  1  1.00
2  4  4.95
3  0  4.90
4  0  4.85
5  1  5.79
6  2  7.72
7  3 10.61
8  0 10.50
9  0 10.40
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample of `test` and the expected output from that sample data.

Comment: Ooops good point @r2evans - have now updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using `accumulate` from the `purrr` package. The `accumulate` function can apply a function with two arguments, such as `x` and `y`, to a sequence of vector. The return value would become the input value of the next round.

In the following example, I asked the `accumulate` function to begin at the second number of the `In` column to the end. I also provided `1` to the `.init` argument, which will be the first `x` to the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(In = c(1,4,0,0,1,2,3,0,0), Vol = c(1,rep(NA,8)))

df %>% 
  mutate(Vol = accumulate(In[2:n()], function(x, y) (x + y) * 0.99, .init = 1))
#   In       Vol
# 1  1  1.000000
# 2  4  4.950000
# 3  0  4.900500
# 4  0  4.851495
# 5  1  5.792980
# 6  2  7.715050
# 7  3 10.607900
# 8  0 10.501821
# 9  0 10.396803
```

In addition, it seems like the first value from the `Vol` column is the same as the first value of the `In` column. If what you are trying to do is `accumulate` the process simply on the `In` column, the following code would be more concise and you don't even need to copy the first value to the `Vol` column.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Vol = accumulate(In, function(x, y) (x + y) * 0.99))
#   In       Vol
# 1  1  1.000000
# 2  4  4.950000
# 3  0  4.900500
# 4  0  4.851495
# 5  1  5.792980
# 6  2  7.715050
# 7  3 10.607900
# 8  0 10.501821
# 9  0 10.396803
```

Comment: It seems to be getting really close to a `stats::filter` function - `filter(df$In, c(1,-0.01), sides=1, method="rec")` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for sharing. The output of your code is `1.00000  5.00000  4.99000  4.94000  5.89010  7.84070 10.78180 10.70339 10.59557`, which is different than the expected output from the OP.

Comment: I know, which is why I said "*getting really close to...*" - I thought it might be helpful for trying to convert this to a vectorised function.

Comment: @thelatemail I see. Yes, it is close. It would be great if this can be further developed to a base R solution.

Comment: Oh I think this is what I want, I'll see how it goes with my real data and see if there is anything I'm missing. Just a coincidence that In and first value of Vol were the same

Comment: @www - of course, the base R version of your answer (which is really just a bunch of hidden loops), is `Reduce(function(x, y) (x + y) * 0.99, df$In, accumulate=TRUE)`

Comment: @d.b - all good on the answer - just leave it, it's useful and I don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `Reduce`

```
transform(df, 
          Vol = Reduce(function(x, y){
              x + y - 0.01 * (x + y)    
          },
          c(df$Vol[1], df$In[-1]),
          accumulate = TRUE))
#  In       Vol
#1  1  1.000000
#2  4  4.950000
#3  0  4.900500
#4  0  4.851495
#5  1  5.792980
#6  2  7.715050
#7  3 10.607900
#8  0 10.501821
#9  0 10.396803
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using `sapply` from base `R` to replace @Ronak’s `for` loop.  `invisible` is not a necessary function but just wrapped around `sapply` to make it work silently.

```
invisible(
  sapply(2:nrow(df), function(i) {
    df$Vol[i] <<- (df$Vol[i-1] + df$In[i]) -  (df$Vol[i-1] + df$In[i])*0.01
  }
         )
)

> df
  In       Vol
1  1  1.000000
2  4  4.950000
3  0  4.900500
4  0  4.851495
5  1  5.792980
6  2  7.715050
7  3 10.607900
8  0 10.501821
9  0 10.396803
```

microbenchmark:

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
           tidy1  578.614  602.3825  736.8518  647.7345  792.1560  3409.963   100
           tidy2  566.256  601.1450 1524.3789  646.5240  801.3490 80219.732   100
        for.loop 4936.829 5288.2650 6007.9584 5635.4895 6540.4290  8982.346   100
          sapply  198.919  218.8710  305.8182  226.3600  243.1750  4489.870   100
 trans.db.reduce  127.456  149.8150  175.4649  172.6280  195.9935   292.835   100
        trans.db  217.416  236.1150  328.3348  255.2275  285.5560  5805.963   100
```

Comment: You should repeat your benchmark and include @d.b's solution, it's fastest.

Comment: @jay.sf, seems like @d.b's function with `Reduce` is fastest.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a trivial task to get values from previous row and update value in current row. However, `mutate` has no "knowledge" of the previous `Vol` value it calculated because it calculates the value of the entire column together.

In such cases, we can use a simple `for` loop

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
   df$Vol[i] = (df$Vol[i-1] + df$In[i]) -  (df$Vol[i-1] + df$In[i])*0.01
}

df
#  In       Vol
#1  1  1.000000
#2  4  4.950000
#3  0  4.900500
#4  0  4.851495
#5  1  5.792980
#6  2  7.715050
#7  3 10.607900
#8  0 10.501821
#9  0 10.396803
```

**data**

```
test = c(1, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(In = test, Vol = c(1,rep(NA,8)))
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your answer, I was hoping to avoid a for loop as in real life I have a very large amount of data and it will be grouped by other columns and I just generally try to avoid them. Maybe I have no choice in this case though

Comment: @user2738526 yes, I have been through such instances myself and it bugs me that I can't do any such calculation without a `for` loop. You can wait for some time and see if anybody else has got a better/intelligent solution to this. Would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can use some algebraic manipulation to express all `Vol` in terms of the first `Vol`

```
transform(df, Vol = c(df$Vol[1], sapply(2:NROW(df), function(n){
    0.99^(n-1) * df$Vol[1] + sum(0.99^((n-1):1) * df$In[2:n])
})))
#  In       Vol
#1  1  1.000000
#2  4  4.950000
#3  0  4.900500
#4  0  4.851495
#5  1  5.792980
#6  2  7.715050
#7  3 10.607900
#8  0 10.501821
#9  0 10.396803
```